# To compare a String Column of a Dataframe 'df1' with another String Column of a Dataframe 'df2' based on which other columns are compared

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, dataframe

**Input Explained:**
I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`, which holds columns as mentioned below.

`df1`

```
Description   Col1    Col2
AAA           1.2     2.5
BBB           1.3     2.0
CCC           1.1     2.3
```

`df2`

```
Description   Col1    Col2
AAA           1.2     1.3
BBB           1.3     2.0
```

**Scenario:**
Have to compare `df1['Description']` and `df2['Description']`, when both equals then have to compare `df1['Col1']` with `df2['Col1']` and `df1['Col2']` with `df2['Col2']` and produce result as expected below.

**Expected Output:**

```
Description    Col1    Col2   Col1_Result           Col2_Result
AAA            1.2     2.5    Pass                  Fail
BBB            1.3     2.0    Pass                  Pass
CCC            1.1     2.3    Not found in df2      Not found in df2
```

**Tried Code:**
Have tried out the below mentioned codeline for above mentioned scenario but doesn't works. Throughs error *"ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"*

```
df1['Col1_Result'] = np.where(df1['Description']== df2['Description'],np.where(df1['Col1'] == df2['Col1'], 'Pass', 'Fail'),'Not found in df2')
df1['Col2_Result'] = np.where(df1['Description']== df2['Description'],np.where(df1['Col2'] == df2['Col2'], 'Pass', 'Fail'),'Not found in df2')
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join for output DataFrame, then select added columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and create output by compare values first for missing values and then columns each other in [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df1['desc'] = df1['Description'].str.lower() 
df2['desc'] = df2['Description'].str.lower()
df = (df1.merge(df2, on='desc', suffixes=['', '_Result'], how='left')
         .drop(['Description_Result','desc'], axis=1))

df3 = df.filter(like='_Result')
new = df3.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_Result',''))

df[df3.columns] = np.select([new.isna(), 
                             df[new.columns].eq(new)], 
                            ['Not found in df2', 'Pass'], 'Fail')
print (df)
  Description  Col1  Col2       Col1_Result       Col2_Result
0         AAA   1.2   2.5              Pass              Fail
1         BBB   1.3   2.0              Pass              Pass
2         CCC   1.1   2.3  Not found in df2  Not found in df2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df3)
   Col1_Result  Col2_Result
0          1.2          1.3
1          1.3          2.0
2          NaN          NaN

print (new)
   Col1  Col2
0   1.2   1.3
1   1.3   2.0
2   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution, it works great! But, the comparison should not be case sensitive. Here, when df1['Col1']='Ddd' and df2['Col1']='DDD' condition assings result as "Not found in df2". This should not be the case. Result should be 'Pass'. Is there any possible way for this ?!

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanien - thank you, change `df[new.columns].eq(new)` to `df[new.columns].astype(str).str.lower().eq(new.astype(str).str.lower())`

Comment: Oops! I mean df1['Description']='Ddd' and df2['Description']='DDD' , and so 'Col1_Result' and 'Col2_Result' assings 'NaN' which in turn we arrive at "Not found in df2"

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanien - then use `df1['Description'] = df1['Description'].str.lower()` `df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].str.lower()` before my soution

Comment: Nope! This might change the original Description to be, since we carry it till result, which should not happen.

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanien - Answer was edited for first 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, code below works with the example given. If there are edge cases, it could be modified as needed.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Description':['AaA', 'BBB','CCC'],
    'Col1': [1.2,1.3,1.1],
    'Col2':[2.5,2.0,2.3]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Description': ['AAA', 'BBB'],
    'Col1': [1.2, 1.3],
    'Col2': [1.3, 2.0]
})

# Convert to lower case
df1['Description'] = df1['Description'].str.lower()
df2['Description'] = df2['Description'].str.lower()

# Merge df
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Description', how='left')


# Compare
df['Col1_result'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Not found in df2' if (pd.isna(x['Col1_y'])) else
                                        'Pass' if x['Col1_x']==x['Col1_y'] else
                                        'Fail', axis=1)
df['Col2_result'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Not found in df2' if (pd.isna(x['Col2_y'])) else
                                        'Pass' if x['Col2_x']==x['Col2_y'] else
                                        'Fail', axis=1)

# Keep only columns from df1
df = df.drop(['Col1_y', 'Col2_y'], axis=1)
# Remove '_x' from column names
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'_x$', '')

# Change to upper case
df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.upper()
```

Output

```
df

  Description  Col1  Col2       Col1_result       Col2_result
0         AAA   1.2   2.5              Pass              Fail
1         BBB   1.3   2.0              Pass              Pass
2         CCC   1.1   2.3  Not found in df2  Not found in df2
```

Comment: Updated code above to handle mix of upper and lower cases such as `AAA` or `AaA`

Comment: Nope! This might change the original Description to be, since we carry it till result, which should not happen.

Comment: Updated the code to change the case of `Description` to upper case i.e now same as original.

Comment: This doesn't work out if in case String is 'Aa', coz at the end it might change the whole string to Upper case. Anyways Thank You for your help mate! Found solution.